# Error in my Django code in model.py part

Tags: python, django, module, django-cms

I am learning to make models in django. But when I'm trying to do the migrations I get an error message as the owner part has an error in `get_full_name` of the first class and also in the return of the movie class.

The errors that come out are the following: between line 23,20 the`ForeignKey` has not `` get_full_name'` member and that both rate as rate_count are not as defined variables. I leave the code here.

```
`from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

User= get_user_model()`

class MoveList(models.Model):
    #modelo de lista para ver
    name= models.CharField('Nombre de la Lista', max_length=50, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField('movies.Movie')


    def __str__(self):
        return "'{list}' de {owner}".format(
            list =self.name,
            owner =self.owner.get_full_name()
        )

class Movie(models.Model):
    #Modelo de peliculas
    name= models.CharField('Nombre de la pelicula',max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField('Fecha de estreno')
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField('Total de claificaciones de la pelicula',blank=True, null=True)
    rate_count = models.PositiveIntegerField('Veces que se ha calificado a la pelicula',blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('movies.Tag')
    studio = models.ForeignKey ('movies.Studio',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    director =models.ForeignKey('movies.Director',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def average_rate(self):
        """"devuelve la calificación"""

        if self.rate_count == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return rate/rate_count

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two questions here.

For your second question, replace:

```
return rate/rate_count
```

by:

```
return self.rate/self.rate_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making "average_rate" into a property with the @property decorator? If you intend to use this calculated property in a template (and you don't need to add in any parameters), I would recommend doing so.

It looks like you're using rate and rate_count without a "self." accessor, which is why they're showing up as unnamed.

```
@property
def average_rate(self):
    """"devuelve la calificación"""

    if self.rate_count == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return self.rate/self.rate_count
```

With regards to "get_full_name", not sure why it's not working properly. Sounds like it's grabbing the model field class instead of the instance and its value.